# checkout_cart_save_after is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, extensions, magento-1.9.3.2

The little project is to **export all items** (sku and quantity) of an **order** using the **Magento (1.9.3.2)** events.

My NvM2MfExport.xml in /app/etc/modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <NvM2MfExport>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Checkout />
            </depends>
        </NvM2MfExport>
    </modules>
</config>
```

My config.xml in /app/code/community/NV/M2MfExport/etc:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

    <modules>
        <NvM2MfExport>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </NvM2MfExport>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <nvm2mfexport>
                <class>Nv_Export_Model</class>
            </nvm2mfexport>
        </models>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <nvm2mfexport>
                        <class>nvm2mfexport/observer</class>
                        <method>orderExport</method>
                    </nvm2mfexport>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_save_after>
        </events>       
    </global>

</config>
```

My Observer.php in /app/code/community/Nv/M2MfExport/Model:

```
<?php

class Nv_Export_Model_Observer 
{
    public function orderExport($observer) 
    {
        //require_once '../app/Mage.php';
        //Mage::app();

        // Übergebenes Quote und Order Objekt holen
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        // Nur schicken wenn tatsächlich eine Adresse zugewiesen wurde
        if ($quote->getDistributorEmail()) 
        {
            // Lieferadresse als Text formatiert holen
            $shipTo = $order->getShippingAddress()->format('text');
            $itemsTxt = "Items\n-----------------------\n";

            foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
                $itemsTxt .= 'SKU: ' . $item->getSku() . ' QTY: ' . $item->getQtyOrdered() . "\n";

            $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
                ->setFromEmail('~@~.de')
                ->setSubject('Neue Bestellung')
                ->setToEmail('~@~.de')
                ->setBody("Lieferadresse:\n\n" . $shipTo . "\n" . $itemsTxt)
                ->send();
        }

        /*$myfile = fopen("/var/www/magento-1.9.3.2/newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt = "John Doe\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        $txt = "Jane Doe\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        fclose($myfile);*/
    }
}
```

The module is shown in the admin and enabled.

After a successfully order submit inside the backend (admin) I expected getting an email with some information. But nothing - not even a system log entry (logging is set on).

I also changed something in my php file that should result in throwing an error and another log entry. But nothing too. That's why I suggest that my Observer.php will not be called.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update some of the names.

Rename **NvM2MfExport.xml** to **Nv_M2MfExport.xml** and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Nv_M2MfExport>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Checkout />
            </depends>
        </Nv_M2MfExport>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Update your **config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

    <modules>
        <Nv_M2MfExport>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Nv_M2MfExport>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <nvm2mfexport>
                <class>Nv_M2MfExport_Model</class>
            </nvm2mfexport>
        </models>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <nvm2mfexport>
                        <class>nvm2mfexport/observer</class>
                        <method>orderExport</method>
                    </nvm2mfexport>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_save_after>
        </events>       
    </global>

</config>
```

Your observer class is also wrong.

```
<?php

class Nv_M2MfExport_Model_Observer 
{
    public function orderExport($observer) 
    {
        //require_once '../app/Mage.php';
        //Mage::app();

        // Übergebenes Quote und Order Objekt holen
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        // Nur schicken wenn tatsächlich eine Adresse zugewiesen wurde
        if ($quote->getDistributorEmail()) 
        {
            // Lieferadresse als Text formatiert holen
            $shipTo = $order->getShippingAddress()->format('text');
            $itemsTxt = "Items\n-----------------------\n";

            foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
                $itemsTxt .= 'SKU: ' . $item->getSku() . ' QTY: ' . $item->getQtyOrdered() . "\n";

            $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
                ->setFromEmail('~@~.de')
                ->setSubject('Neue Bestellung')
                ->setToEmail('~@~.de')
                ->setBody("Lieferadresse:\n\n" . $shipTo . "\n" . $itemsTxt)
                ->send();
        }

        /*$myfile = fopen("/var/www/magento-1.9.3.2/newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt = "John Doe\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        $txt = "Jane Doe\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        fclose($myfile);*/
    }
}
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will never give you anything:

```
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
```

Because the `checkout_cart_save_after` event only lets you retrieve the cart, see in `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart` :

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_save_after', array('cart'=>$this));
```

So, you can do the following:

```
$cart = $observer->getEvent()->getCart();
$quote = $cart->getQuote();
```

But you still have the problem of retrieving the corresponding order information. The reason behind that is because **this event is not triggered necessarily after an order is placed, it's triggered after a change happens to the cart.** So if one updates the quantity of an item in the cart, it's gonna trigger it and there's no order linked to it.

IMHO you should use the `sales_order_place_after` event and do the following:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$quote = $order->getQuote();
```

Comment: Raphael, could you please have a look at the similar issue with a event at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/339514/magento-2-4-2-event-checkout-cart-save-after-doesnt-seem-to-be-observed-by-my?